# look for json key to print it's content without brackets in python

Tags: python, json

i'm relatively new to python/programming and even more of a noob in json.

I am making a dictionary app for a side projects that I have, it works fine, I can search for words and get their definition, but I want to make it perfect and I want the results to be readable for the final user (I know about indenting but I don't want the brackets and all the json formatting to appear in the results)

So this is the json i'm pulling the data from:

```
{
 "Bonjour": {
  "English Word": "Hello",
  "Type of word": "whatever",
  "Defintion": "Means good day",
  "Use case example": "Bonjour igo",
  "Additional information": "BRO"
 }
}
```

and this is the code i'm using to get the values (it doesn't work), the "search" variable is = to "Bonjour" in this case (it's a user input)

```
currentword = json.load(data) #part of the "with open..."


for definition in currentword[search]['English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example']:
    print(definition)
```

the error I get is the following:

```
KeyError: ('English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example')
```

Now i'm unsure if "Bonjour" is the key or "English Word", etc... are the keys, if not, what is "Bonjour"

Anyways, I want it to print the values of "English Word" and preferably as "English Word - VALUE/DEFINITION"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your problem, looks like you want to extract only some of the key-value pairs from your existing dictionary.

Try like below:

```
data = {
 "Bonjour": {
  "English Word": "Hello",
  "Type of word": "whatever",
  "Definition": "Means good day",
  "Use case example": "Bonjour igo",
  "Additional information": "BRO"
  }
  }

currentword = data
search = "Bonjour"

result = dict((k, currentword[search][k]) for k in ['English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example'])

for k,v in result.items():
    print k + ":" + v
```

**Result:**

```
Definition:Means good day 
English Word:Hello 
Use case example:Bonjour igo
```

Comment: thanks for showing me the way to do it, but could you explain why it is like this? for example why can't I use search directly instead of using "search_word" variable
Thanks

Comment: You need to use search_word, it gives you the dictionary related to "Bonjour" alone. Current_word contains the full dictionary and I assume it will have many words like Bonjour.

Comment: And also i'd like to not have the brackets and have each definition on a separate line

Comment: @Flexy, if the answer helped you, please consider upvoting too. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have 15 reputation yet :(

Comment: No Issues. Thanks @Flexy! :)

Answer (score 3):

`JSON` format is simply a nice way to pair keys and values.
`Keys` are the names we give to `Values`, so it will be easy to access them.
If we took your JSON, and split it by keys and values, this is what we would get:
Keys: `"Bonjour", "English Word", "Type of word", "Defintion", "Use case example", "Additional information"`.

Showing all values is a little complex, so I'll explain:
The value of "Bonjour" is this:

```
{
  "English Word": "Hello",
  "Type of word": "whatever",
  "Defintion": "Means good day",
  "Use case example": "Bonjour igo",
  "Additional information": "BRO"
}
```

And all other value are described in the value of "Bonjour".
The value of "English Word" is "Hello" and so on.

When you write a line like so: `currentword[search]['English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example']`, you are telling Python to look for a key named `('English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example')`, and obviously it does not exist.

What you should do is as follows:

```py
for definition in currentword[search]:
    eng_word = definition['English Word']
    print('English Word - {}'.format(eng_word))
```

please note that `definition` contain all other fields as well, so you can choose whichever one you like.

Comment: thanks you for helping, I wish I could give you upvote but i'm too new

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
currentword[search]['English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example']
```

Calls `'English Word', 'Definition', 'Use case example'` as a tuple key from the inner dict, which doesn't exist in your dictionary, which is why a `KeyError` is raised.

If you want just the english word, use this instead:

```
currentword[search]["English Word"]
```

Assuming `search` is `"Bonjour"`.

It also looks like you are also trying to filter out specific keys from the inner dict  separately. If this is the case, you can do this:

```
d = {
 "Bonjour": {
  "English Word": "Hello",
  "Type of word": "whatever",
  "Defintion": "Means good day",
  "Use case example": "Bonjour igo",
  "Additional information": "BRO"
 }
}

inner_dict = d['Bonjour']

keys = ["English Word", "Use case example", "Defintion"]

print({k: inner_dict[k] for k in keys})
# {'English Word': 'Hello', 'Use case example': 'Bonjour igo', 'Defintion': 'Means good day'}
```

Comment: I have not verified it because the the code posted by another person worked, but still, thanks